# VB.Net and youtube videos

Tags: vb.net, youtube

Is it even possible to create a code that will

> Contain in a textfile url addresses to youtube videos
>   Then the videos would be played inner the application via Media Player? maybe or something else
>   Would the program know when the video ended to start next one?
>   Would I be able to control start stop next shuffle pause from the program buttons?

Really thanks for your answers.

Please give me some hints meanwhile cause I couldn't find any solutions how to get something like that

Comment: interesting question,  hmm it *would* help though if you had some code tat you tried already

Comment: Well I don't have I have a player that gets just the file names from a .txt files it can be a local path c:/etc.. or a direct mp3 link.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a webbrowser that would navigate to the page plus "/#movie_player" then it would only display the player and not the rest of the page. Use "Inspect Element" in firefox to see this.

Ex. youtube.com/video_url/**#movie_player**

Answer (score 0):

you need a shock wave flash element and you can turn that using Flash
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMYmnWdCxvs

`convert = TextBox1.Text
    convert = Replace(convert, "=", "/")
    convert2 = Replace(convert, "watch?", "")`